# Android Button Height in Layout not filling the parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I've Created this layout and I don't know why `Button`'s height not filling the layout height

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
    >

  <View
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:background="@color/pf_sm_dividor_light"
      />

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button">

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/li_icon"
          android:layout_width="24dp"
          android:layout_height="24dp"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:src="@drawable/pf_ic_main"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
          android:contentDescription="@string/pf_app_name" />

      <TextView
          style="@style/pf.TextView.sm_title"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
          android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
          android:text="Text Here"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/li_icon"
          android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pf_sm_ktext" />

      <ir.system.views.KText
          style="@style/pf.TextView.sm_title"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:textStyle="normal"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
          android:text="1,500"
          android:textSize="22sp"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:id="@+id/pf_sm_ktext" />

    </RelativeLayout>
<!-- Here is the Button -->
    <Button
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/pf_btn"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        />
  </RelativeLayout>

  <View
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:background="@color/pf_sm_dividor_dark"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

but result is something like this :

[image: Pejman Chatrrooz]

emulator android 4.0 result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic concept for your problem ..

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >



        <ImageButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            />


        </LinearLayout>
```

Using Relative layout try this :

```
<RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/li_icon"
          android:layout_width="24dp"
          android:layout_height="24dp"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:layout_marginLeft="9dp" 
          android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
          android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
          android:text="Text Here"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/li_icon"
          android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pf_sm_ktext" />




<!-- Here is the Button -->
    <Button
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rl"
        />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Using Linear Layout try this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:background="@color/red"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Android Hacker"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/black"

            ></LinearLayout>

        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="okay"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="@color/brown"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: But I want to do it with `RelativeLayout`

Comment: whats the issue with using LinearLayout ?

Comment: I wonna add some relative views after this. and it's really important to create it with this relative layout.

Comment: Using weight in Linear Layout can solve your problem. Let me know if you are using a list view ?

Comment: no it's not a list view and it's just an item for my main layout. and this is really important to use `RelativeLayout` what is wrong with this relative layout? it's relly wired, isn't it ? could this be a bug ?

Comment: @Omid Try my code in new XML file. Wonder how stuff happened and then use that in your code. I have posted that one after testing. This fulfills all your requirement i.e the way you like to be. It might differ in real scenario. I just put an idea for that. Be cool and try stuff.

Comment: @AndroidHacker look, in editor works fine, but on emulator and my device not working as I expected, and i cant add my button in my master relativelayout because that relativelayout has margin to parent.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42576/discussion-between-androidhacker-and-omid)

Answer (score -3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/li_icon"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pf_sm_ktext"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/li_icon"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:text="Text Here" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pf_sm_ktext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:text="1,500"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <!-- Here is the Button -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:text="+" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is what i did in editor and it shows the way you want, juts try it once how it looks like to you

Comment: my code in editor works fine! but in my device is how i explained, let me check it on emulator 4.0

Comment: I've test it, and there is same result.

Comment: its not working over device?, i just pushed it over my phone running in 4.2 and its displaying me your expected result.

Comment: try this,android:layout_height="wrap_content" change this to        android:layout_height="match_parent" for second relative layout and see result.

Comment: tried it and same result, but my button is in first relative layout

Comment: Very strange, just edited my answer again try this out, for me it seems to be working both in device and editor.