# Set two TextViews and one ImageView in LinearLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout   
      <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>
      <**Add textView1 here**> 
      <ImageView>
      <**Add textView2 here**>
      <ScrollView
           <LinearLayout
             <ImageView>
             <ListView>
      >
    >
 >
```

I am trying to add them such that after youtube player textView1,imageView & textView2 come horizontally aligned.I have tried using `RelativeLayout` there instead of `LinearLayout` but that is not showing either of these three widgets.

Comment: Check out my post over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397575/android-button-height-in-layout-not-filling-the-parent/20397742#20397742

Comment: You basically want the youtube player to be on top of the textview1,imageview and textview2 (which are on a same "row")?

Comment: @MarioStoilov You figured it out right buddy thats my requirement.

Comment: Check out this link, it should help you http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/2010/07/03/introduction-to-android-ui-layouts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do something like this (lacking a proper editor at work, sorry):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <**Add textView1 here**> 
            <ImageView>
            <**Add textView2 here**>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The idea is to add an Horizonrally oriented LinearLayout, and put the views inside.

Comment: how do I achieve it ?