# Android Button Customization

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, interface

May i ask how to put `icon on my button` like the image below?

And also where can i have resources or `sample resources of buttons` like this?

[image]

Comment: Check out my post over here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397575/android-button-height-in-layout-not-filling-the-parent/20397742#20397742 .. Simply replace with Image and place as you desire.

Comment: Check out my post over here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397575/android-button-height-in-layout-not-filling-the-parent/20397742#20397742 .. Simply replace with Image and place as you desire.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set the drawable to the left of your `Button`. Either via [xml](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableLeft) or [programmatically](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: do you have a sample of it?

Comment: samples are all over the net, sir.

Comment: Since there is no code from your side to add to, I'll stick with @Nfear's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Either create a button and set a compound drawable or create an ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/login_with_facebook"
          android:layout_width="100dp"
          android:height="48dp"
          android:text="FACEBOOK"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:drawableLeft="@drawable/facebook_icon_48_x_48"
          android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: textview? what i was asking was button sir. Thanks.

Comment: sir, its clickable as you can see, and user won't see any difference if this button or textview

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
         android:text="facebook"/>
```

If u want space between image and text, then give drawablePadding Like:

```
<Button android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
         android:text="facebook"
         android:drawablePadding="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

using `RelativeLayout` it can be done easily. here I got snippet for you,

```
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/fb_logo_button"
            android:text=""
            android:background="fb_logo"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

        <Button 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fb_logo_button"
            android:id="@+id/fb_text_button"
            android:text="Facebook"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

this will ensure that whatever your images are for respective `DPI`s, it will align this layout to center horizontally. Within this layout logo will be always to left of text as in picture.

This is applicable when your parent is also a `RelativeLayout`. If you got `LinearLayout` as parent then in above `RelativeLayout` tag change `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` to `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

I can't test it in eclipse as I'm out of home. Try this and let me know. Thanks.